# Bind ObservableCollection to a DataGrid after assigning new value

Tags: data-binding, datagrid, silverlight-3.0, observablecollection

It seems to be a simple problem, but I can't get it to work.

I have a UserControl with the following property:

```
public ObservableCollection<HL7Message> source {get; set;}
```

And the following Binding:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgMessages" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding source}" ></data:DataGrid>
```

from a parent UserControl I set the value upon a button click:

```
messagesGrid.source = src; //messagesGrid is the name of the UserCntrol above
```

I'm expecting my DataGrid to be updated, but it's not. Can you please point at what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) sadly do not support change-notification. Therefore the DataGrid will not know that the collection has been changed if you set the `source`-Property.

One possibility is to implement [INotifiyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for the `messagesGrid.source`-Property:

```
class YourUserControlClass: INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {    
    if (null != PropertyChanged) {        
           PropertyChanged(this,e);    
    }
  }

  ObservableCollection<HL7Message> m_source;

  public ObservableCollection<HL7Message> Source { g
        get{return m_source;}
        set{
            if(value != m_source){
                 m_source=value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("Source");
            } 
        }
  } 
  ....
```

Please note, I have written the first letter of `Source` in UpperCase because in .net, properties are generally written so. You have to change your binding accordingly because Bindings are case sensitive.

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgMessages" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" ></data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! As I pointed below, I was confused by the fact that ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and I couldn't make out what it means.

Comment: Another question - would that be correct if I just put `dgMessages.ItemsSource = _source;` into the "set" section of my property

Comment: @Masha: If you don't call OnPropertyChanged("Source") then it will not work. But if you ask for ommiting the if-statement, this would work. However I personally find it bad practice to raise a change-notification, if there is no real change.

Comment: I get your point, but I was talking about omitting the whole `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and just putting `dgMessages.ItemsSource = _source;` into the Set (you're right, I should use an if-statement there in any case), because all I need to do basically is to update my dataGrid with whatever ObservableCollection<> gets passed to it.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, if you set the source of the DataGrid directly. Don't know if this is meaningfull in your application, but this will do. However I would recommend you really to dig into this INotifyPropertyChanged-thing and probably also into DependencyProperties. This is really an essential part of WPF and if you got it you will love it. You need it for example also for the MVVM-pattern, which is great for coding WPF!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the reference for `source` changes on your button click, there is nothing to tell the UI to update itself.  You will either need to make `source` a dependency property, or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter for `source`.

```
private ObservableCollection<HL7Message> source;
public ObservableCollection<HL7Message> Source 
{ 
  get
  {
    return this.source;
  }

  set
  {
    this.source = value;
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Source);
  }
}
```

Comment: What got me confused is the fact that ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged (read about it somewhere on MSDN), or does it mean that there is NotifyPropertyChanged() event is available for me?

Comment: As for dependency property, MSDN says: In order to be the source of a binding, a property does not need to be a dependency property; you can use any CLR property as a binding source. However, in order to be the target of a binding, the property must be a dependency property. So I don't think I can use it..