# How to make WPF DataGrid display up-to-date content?

Tags: wpf, database, binding, datagrid

Right now I have a WPF `DataGrid` that displays a list obtained from a LINQ to Entity query. That however does not mean that if I delete something from my data base, it'll be removed immediately from the `DataGrid`. I tried `myGrid.Items.Refresh()`, but it refreshed  only one cell.

I know the `ObservableCollection` could somehow solve the problem but I don't know where to create such collection and proper methods so that whenever I create/add/modify database, the collections gets modified too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid has the data from the time the query was run.
If you want fresh data you need to rerun the query.

[Query Notifications in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

If you are not using MSSQL let me know and I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to interact with the DataGrid through code. Instead, bind the DataGrid's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and manipulate the collection. The DataGrid will update automagically.

Take a look here: [Bind ObservableCollection to a DataGrid after assigning new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998255/bind-observablecollection-to-a-datagrid-after-assigning-new-value)

In fact, you will realize that in a lot of cases (in my case it's 95% of the time), you don't want to give any name to your WPF control. If your code don't know about your UI, it's easier to maintain in the long run. Let your UI know where to fetch its information through databinding. And take a look at INotifyPropertyChanged or Dependency Properties, and DataContext.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />


public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    ObservableCollection<object> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> MyCollection
    {
    get
    {
        return myCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        myCollection = value;
        // Call the Notification here. Using linq and reflection you could get it to look like this:
        // NotifyPropertyChanged(() => MyCollection);
    }
}
```

You don't need to provide change notifications if you don't actually change the myCollection value. ObservableCollection actually provides its own changes when you modify the collection.